# How to add Node.js path in WebStorm using Linux

Tags: node.js, configuration, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 19.3.1 on Linux Mint Cinnamon 19. I am trying to add a path for node.js to debug my code in WebStorm. The path for node.js is /usr/bin/nodejs, when I go to this directory I can find nodejs file there, but when I open WebStorm and try to  access this path from there, It doesn't show node.js file inside. 
 The permissions for node.js are Read And write, should I add execute too for the root?

If you know how to solve the problem please help me to fix it out. 
Thanks in advance.

I've seen people on internet simply opening the path from Webstorm, but in my case it doesn't show.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7ydvEh9WLQ check out this link.

//There is no code actually

Expecting to have configurations correctly set up)

Comment: does `/usr/bin/nodejs` have executable permissions? Can you run your apps in terminal using `/usr/bin/nodejs path/to/your/js`?

Comment: Yes, for example in VS Code I can use built in terminal with node.js, but when I try to integrate node path with WebStorm, it doesn't show  node.js in  /usr/bin  repository.

Comment: please try running the command in system terminal, not in vscode. Also, what about executable permissions?

Comment: Dear Lena, just tried as you said. I run javascript file from my system terminal and it worked. The permissions for nodejs file are
 52168588 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Oct 17  2018 nodejs -> node 

Read and Write I guess)

Comment: does it work if you enter the path `/usr/bin/nodejs` manually in the **Node.js Interpreter** field?

Comment: Yes, it does. I never had a problem working with node.js, can't solve this problem. Thought maybe someone else has faced this problem before